# syntax error in ocaml because of String.concat

Tags: ocaml

Lets say I have a list of type integer [blah;blah;blah;...] and i don't know the size of the lis and I want to pattern match and  not print the first element of the list. Is there any way to do this without using a if else case or having a syntax error?
because all i'm trying to do is parse a file tha looks like a/path/to/blah/blah/../file.c
and only print the path/to/blah/blah

for example, can it be done like this?

```
let out x = Printf.printf " %s \n" x 
let _ = try
      while true do
           let line = input_line stdin in 
           ...
           let rec f (xpath: string list) : ( string list ) =
                begin match  Str.split (Str.regexp "/") xpath  with 
                         | _::rest -> out (String.concat "/" _::xpath);
                         | _ -> ()
        end
```

but if i do this i have a syntax error at the line of String.concat!!

Comment: Your code is incomplete. The function `f` is not used recursively and doesn't produce values, only side effects. The scope of the function `f` is not closed and the function is not used at all. The loop is not closed (no `done` keyword). The exception guard is not closed and misses "catch" branches (no corresponding `with` keyword).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`String.concat "/" _::xpath` doesn't mean anything because `_` is pattern but not a value. `_` can be used in the left part of a pattern matching but not in the right part.

What you want to do is `String.concat "/" rest`.

Even if `_::xpath` were correct, `String.concat "/" _::xpath` would be interpreted as `(String.concat "/" _)::xpath` whereas you want it to be interpreted as `String.concat "/" (_::xpath)`.

Comment: sorry, in the mean time i already replace xpath by rest still doesn't work !! and i didn't do it  
on purpose to ask the question twice:p